# Cannot redirect to error page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

I had the following action.

```
// POST: /Venue/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")] 
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SqlException), View = "DbError")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
```

And I tried to raise an error by deleting a FK referred row and the following page is shown in the elmah page. However, it still redirected to the standard error page.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.......
```

The `DbError.cshtml` has the following content.

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">@Model.Exception</h2>
```

I expected the detail description of the `SqlException` been shown up.